# Openshift 3 communication between deployments

Tags: openshift

I'm just learning OSE 3. I'd like to deploy two Node.js Web applications I have created. So I have created a Project with two Node.js deployments, which are now running in their own Pod.
My question is, how are they supposed to communicate ? say for example one application needs to redirect to the other, or include components from the other application.
Should I hardcode the route of each application in a configuration file or so ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For internal communication between the two services, you can use the name of the service as the host name when making connections. This is possible because the name of the services are added to an internal DNS server so that a host name lookup on the name will yield the correct IP for the service at that time. When the service has multiple pods, an internal IP load balancer will automatically route the request to one of the pods.

For the question about redirects, that seems to suggest you have both services exposed publicly and want to have one service return a HTTP response that redirects the HTTP client to a URL which falls to the other service. What the redirect URL needs to be is going to depend on how you are exposing the services. That is, whether each service is exposed as a different hostname or you have used path based routing of OpenShift to overlay one at a sub URL of the other under the same host.

Either way, you probably want to use an environment variable passed in via the deployment configuration to indicate to the service triggering the redirect, to tell it what the URL prefix is that it needs to redirect to. You would manually set this up. This at least means you haven't hardwired it in your code.

If you mean something else by redirect, you will need to explain better what you mean.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Is there an example code/tutorial which shows the first case you have mentioned ? (using the service as host name).

Comment: What is the name of the service in OpenShift? You just take that name and use that as the hostname in your code, as host name in the address for connecting to a socket, or as part of the URL if using HTTP. Not sure what else can explain since don't know how your code is written.